# Typescript: How to translate a specific library method to a custom type definition

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

There is this JS library called `mtgsdk` which is a wrapper around http calls to [magicthegathering.io](https://magicthegathering.io) API.

I am working on an app using Ionic and since I cannot find any type definitions for this library, I would like to create my own.

I'm struggling on proper writing the `index.d.ts` file.

For instance there is this find by id method that the library give us:

```
const mtg = require('mtgsdk')

mtg.card.find(3)
.then(result => {
    console.log(result.card.name) // "Black Lotus"
})
```

How would the `index.d.ts` looks like in this specific case?

Comment: we would need to know what `mtg` and `card` is.

Comment: I edited the question, `mtg` is the library module, `card` I believe to be a method of the library module. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your export might look something like this:

```
export interface Result {
  card: { name:string }
}
export declare class mtg {
  public static card: {
    find(index: number): Promise<Result>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, is anything wrong with the [ts-sdk library](https://github.com/MagicTheGathering/mtg-sdk-typescript)?
If nothing else it seems to contain the interfaces/type definitions.